# iTextSharp rending html to pdf differently than browser

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext

I'm trying to render a HTML invoice to PDF in my application but the resulting PDF looks different than the page looks in my browser (IE, Chrome and Firefox)

Any idea why? I want the browser output.

HTML

```
<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>
   <tr>
      <td align='center' style='background-color: #18B5F0' colspan = '2'><b>Order Sheet</b></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan = '2'></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><b>Order No: </b>2303</td>
      <td align = 'right'><b>Date: </b>26/10/2016 15:58:52 </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan = '2'><b>Company Name: </b>ASPSnippets</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table border = '1'>
   <tr>
      <th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>ProductId</th>
      <th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>Product</th>
      <th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>Price</th>
      <th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>Quantity</th>
      <th style = 'background-color: #D20B0C;color:#ffffff'>Total</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>101</td>
      <td>Sun Glasses ljkh jkh kj hkjh kjh  kjh kjh kj kjh kj  jkh kj kjh kjh </td>
      <td>200</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>1000</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>Jeans</td>
      <td>400</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>800</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>103</td>
      <td>Trousers</td>
      <td>300</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>900</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>104</td>
      <td>Shirts</td>
      <td>550</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1100</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td align = 'right' colspan = '4'>Total</td>
      <td>3800</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

C#

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(myhtmlstring);

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);    
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream("MyPDF2.pdf", FileMode.Create));

pdfDoc.Open();

XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, pdfDoc, sr);

pdfDoc.Close();
```

PDF
[image: PDF Result]

Browser (Ignore the garbage after Sunglasses)
[image: Browser Result]

Answer (score 1):

I found many posts with exactly the same complaints. 
Apparently the HTML Parser is a bit picky.

I tried http://ironpdf.com/ library which is available on nuget and it converted it exactly as a browser renders it.

[image]

Comment: To understand, IronPDF uses an embedded Chrome rendering engine to give accurate HTML to PDF functionality.

Code to provide this kind of accurate HTML to PDF:

`using IronPdf;
IronPdf.HtmlToPdf Renderer = new IronPdf.HtmlToPdf();
// Render an HTML document or snippet as a string
Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf("<h1>Hello World</h1>").SaveAs("html-string.pdf");`

There is a tutorial on this subject that may help explain the C# Html to PDF settings in detail:   https://ironpdf.com/tutorials/html-to-pdf/

Comment: isn't it available for java ?